# insert data into two table depending on the id from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have table called customers contain custID,custName, another table called products contain proID,proName,price and third table Cust_PRo contain id,custID,proID.
i filled the products with data like this:

```
proID  proName  price
1      potato   100
2      cotton   600
3      rice     200
```

and in another form i have combobox i filled it with products names and textbox to write the customer name and gridview to appear data and there are two buttons one to add the values into grid and second to save it into database.
when i write the customer name and choose the products the data appear in the grid like this:

```
custName  ProName
john      potato
john      cotton 
john      rice
```

as you see one customer can take many products the problem is to add the values into database i want when the user click the save button the data insert into the database like this:

first customers table:

```
custID custName
1       john
```

second Cust_PRo table:

```
id  custID  ProID
1    1       1
2    1       2
3    1       3
```

thank you

Comment: You need to give some more explanantion about the problem you encounter. What kind of SQL statements do you use? Or do you use Entity Framework or some other ORM library?

Comment: I don't know where is your problem yet. It seems like you have to create two tables and create a relationship between them then do the SQL statements correctly.
If you need help with SQL statements, please provide some more information about the statements that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i got you 100% but i think you need some algorithm or something.. anyway

first, you need to generate a `CustID` for your new customer, to do that you need to get the maximum `CustID` from the table `Customers` and add it to 1 to avoid Primary key violation.

```
select max(CustID) from Customers
```

then, you'll be good to go. You have (CustID and ProdID from `comboBox1.SelectedValue;`)

Comment: I'd be more inclined to suggest an identity column and let the database handle the allocation of newly inserted ids.

Comment: yes i have the custID and the proID but there are many proID at the time i mean customer id number 1 have products id numbers 1,2,4,5,3 so how can i add all these values in the Cust_pro table

Answer (score 0):

I added the values to datatable and then used the SqlBulkCopy class to insert these values into database